# Enable Apache Virtualhost Site To Only View Over SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost, security

Viewing site over http and https are both working but prefer to configure it so that ***ALL*** visitors ***ONLY*** go through the SSL connection so that it always start with http**s**://**www**.example.com - what am I missing?

I'm trying to do the following:
visit http ://example.com and go to https ://www.example.com
visit http ://www.example.com and go to https ://www.example.com
visit https ://example.com and go to https ://www.example.com

I created and enabled the file name examplesite (see below) in the folder /etc/apache2/sites-available

```
<VirtualHost example.com:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost www.example.com:443>
  ServerName www.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
  ...
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I'm looking for Virtualhost configuration on apache and not mod_rewrite redirects.  If you have something similar, I'll give it a try.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Looking to have only https viewing over www.example.com and not example.com and right now site is viewable using both http and https.

Answer (score 1):

looks like your first virtualhost does not meet the minimum requirements for a virtualhost

```
 Inside each <VirtualHost> block, you will need at minimum a ServerName directive to designate which host is served and a DocumentRoot directive to show where in the filesystem the content for that host lives.
```

so, add a

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
```

at the first virtualhost and see how that goes

source: [apache.org](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html)

Answer (score 0):

Strange I am looking for the mod_rewrite method and I found this link today:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200501/http-to-https-apache-redirection

VirtualHost entries require IP addresses and will not work with a fqdn.
Change your

to

...

For the second part of your question, redirecting example.com to www.example.com you will need to use the rewrite module:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^example.com [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://www.example.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]

That will add a www on the beginning of all addresses.

Comment: Hi Bryon - it does look similar except that I didn't have NameVirtualHost listed in the first line. Not sure if that makes a difference. Also I do have SSLEngine On since going to the https address does work.

Comment: Ah yes. My mistake. VirtualHost uses an IP address. NameVirtualHost uses the fqdn. If you change your fqdn to a * i suspect it will work. http://serverfault.com/questions/6963/what-is-the-logic-behind-virtualhost-namevirtualhost clarifies the difference.

Comment: Thanks to your tips @Byron, I'm getting somewhere by using *. Each scenario works except the one going from https ://example.com to https ://www.example.com

Comment: Sorry, that was a wrong comment. I think to change that you will have to use the rewrite module. That is the only way I have seen it changed.

Comment: Edited my answer to be more inclusive of the comments.